# How to clear all childViews from ContainerView?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember application with a sidebar with a variable number of widgets in it. I'm using Ember.ContainerView to store the widget views.

Populating the container view works just fine (all the widgets are rendered as they should).

**The problem is** that when I want to update the ContainerView (because the application state changes, new widgets should be loaded), **the current childViews cannot be removed**... If I call `view.removeChild(child)` and `child.remove()` for every childView, only a few actually get removed.

I think this has something to do with Ember updating the DOM for every `remove()` call but I can't figure it out. I've also tried just using `this.set('childViews',[])` instead of removing each view individually but that breaks the entire view.

Am I missing something here?

**Code:**

```
    // Clear current views
    this.get('childViews').forEach(function(_view) {
        view.removeChild(_view);
        _view.remove();
    });

    var view = this,
        childViews = this.get('childViews');

    // Create new views
    this.get('controller.content').forEach(function (widgetData) {
        childViews.pushObject(App.WidgetView.create({
           controller: App.WidgetController.create(widgetData),
           ...
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a removeAllChildren method on Em.ContainerView:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html#method_removeAllChildren

this.removeAllChildren() should do the trick.

Comment: Ok first of all, apologies that I overlooked that method. It does the trick, sort of. The parentView has no more children after the update but they are not removed from the DOM..

Comment: I've tried using `Ember.run.sync()` to force the DOM the update but that doesn't appear to work. I'm currently using a rather ugly `('#'+this.elementId).html('')` right after the `removeAllChildren()` call to achieve that..